# Getting classification result from mahout

Tags: mahout

Finally I am able to train mahout classifier , now my problem is how can i get target category for my input document.

What is the process of getting target category for my text documents ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to vectorize the text document, RandomAccessSparseVector.

Some sample code for your reference:

```
    Vector vector = new RandomAccessSparseVector(FEATURES);
    FeatureExtractor fe = new FeatureExtractor();
    HashSet<String> fs = fe.extract(text);
    for (String s : fs) {
        int index = dictionary.get(s);
        vector.setQuick(index, frequency.get(index));
    }
```

Then, use the Classifier.classify(Vector) to get the result.